# ffmpeg Image Size-Based Pan Zoom

Tags: video, ffmpeg, images

I am trying to programmatically 'Ken Burns' images that are selected randomly from a directory. So far I am able to create the desired effect, a slow scroll down from top to bottom, on an image sized 2844x3358, but I would like to create a similar effect for images of various sizes including... 1200x900image.jpg, 2844x3108image.jpg, 2844x3218image.jpg, 2844x3358image.jpg, 4896x3672image.JPG, etc. Because the final output is to be combined with older(format) video, the output size is 720x480movie.mp4. So far my ffmpeg command looks like

```
ffmpeg -i 2844x3358.jpg \
  -filter_complex \
    "pad=w=8600:h=3600:x='(ow-iw)/2':y='(oh-ih)/2',\
    zoompan=x='(iw-0.625*ih)/2':y='(on/(25*85))*(ih-ih/zoom)'\
    :z='4':d=25*85:s=720x480" \
  -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 720x480movie.mp4
```

I am able to replicate the desired effect using a percentage of input width/height.

```
ffmpeg -i 2844x3358.jpg \
  -filter_complex \
    "pad=w=iw*3:h=ih*1.7:x='(ow-iw)/2':y='(oh-ih)/2',\
    zoompan=x='(iw-0.625*ih)/2':y='(on/(25*85))*(ih-ih/zoom)'\
    :z='4':d=25*85:s=720x480" \
  -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 720x480movie2.mp4
```

But it doesn't work for all image sizes. I have the sense that that this is doable, that I am close, but that I am woefully lacking the requisite skills to solve this problem. Any help in understanding what I'm missing and how to move forward would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why is the pad is present at all?

Comment: As I understand it, the pad is needed to create 'room' for the image to scroll down. You only see a small portion of the image on the screen at any one time.

Comment: You're scolling vertically but you're adding 2x *width* - isn't needed. Vertically, you're only adding 3600-3358=242 pixels. Look into the recently added scroll filter.

Comment: That's exciting! Docs for scroll filter here: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scroll example command line code https://twitter.com/FFmpeg/status/1180179571456372737  and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24316446/generate-video-containing-scrolling-image

Comment: ffmpeg version 4.1.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers 
No such filter: 'scroll'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument

Comment: Get a datestamped build from https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/

Comment: Unfortunately Ye Olde Mac... 
make: *** [build/SDL_cocoawindow.lo] Error 1

Comment: Because the image has a width of 2844px, and I'm zooming x 4, the pad is needed to get the text in my image (handwriting) big enough to read in a scrolling 720x480 sized movie. It works.